# Filtering Alternator A/C whine

Tags: power-supply, dc

I have designed/cobbled together a small BT receiver for my vehicle which is getting some RPM dependent alternator whine due to stray A/C. Though I know this is likely an issue with the battery, the alternator or a ground loop, I would like to build a filter for the power input. I have a couple questions:

1. I am looking at the [TDK ACM70V-701-2PL-TL00](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/datasheets/cmf_automotive_power_acm70v_en.pdf) common mode choke as an input filter for my D/C line. Would this be sufficient on its own, or am I wasting my time without adding a large capacitor to complete the LC filter?
2. If I absolutely need a large capacitor on the input, what's the smallest I could get away with? I'm trying to stay away from electrolytic capacitors due to their large form-factor.

Finally, here is schematic of the D/C input of my circuit:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Do you have a low ESR Cap on this now?  is you Alternator generating that much ripple voltage into a low ESR battery? Can you measure the ripple on AC with DMM?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - Yes I do, C1 seen above is a KEMET T495X107K025ATE150 Tantalum cap. I will try to measure the ripple on the D/C input with my scope :).

Comment: hopefully all 6 diodes are operating with low ripple and your EMI is not coming from somewhere else like ignition.

Comment: C1 is going to fail, and it may do so in an exciting way.  They can burst into flames if their voltage rating is exceeded.  The voltage on your nominally 12VDC car system is normally higher, and can get some really high voltage spikes at times.  Tantalums belong in protected places where you can guarantee that they will never be exposed to more than their rated voltage - like, after a voltage regulator.

Comment: iirc a 3 microfarad capacitor on the output of the aternator is sufficient - usually standard but may have been removed or broken.

Comment: @JRE - Interesting. For 100uF, I'm stuck using an electrolytic then, right?

Comment: @t3ddftw:  Tantalum capacitors are **electrolytic** capacitors.  There are other types of electrolytic capacitors that aren't as exciting, but they can be expensive or larger than the tantalum.  Solid aluminum capacitors should be about the same size as the tantalums and cost more.  Wet aluminum electrolytics (the cheap ones) will be larger for the same capacitance.

Comment: @t3ddftw You should first check if it's scope noise.  Connect probe tip to its ground and see what you get on the scope when you put it near the board.  Next you should check if it's conducted or radiated noise.  Connect the probe to the board and move it around and watch the detected noise on the scope.  How you fix the noise is going to depend on those tests.  A filter may do no good at all.